# Pyodbc invalid column name

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to send a SQL request via Python, in order to query the table Message(DeviceID, CommunicationTime, Data), which is hosted on an Azure SQL database.

My code is below:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
database = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
username = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxx'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

device = 'D1AAAA'
msgTime = '2020-01-15'

with pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT=1433;DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}") as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT DeviceID, CommunicationTime FROM Message WHERE CommunicationTime={msgTime}") AND DeviceID={device}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            while row:
                print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
                row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
```

This code gives me the following error on the line that contains the SQL request:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'D1AAAA'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)"

However, I do not get any error if I remove the `AND DeviceID={device}` from the conditions. Could anyone explain why I get this error?

Comment: Do not embed data *values* into SQL command text. That's called "SQL Injection" and it is a bad practice. Instead, use a *parameterized query* as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters).

Comment: Works wells! Thanks a lot!